# How to setup VLFEAT on Octave?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, octave, vlfeat

The instructions on the official website aren't clear. Does anyone know how to setup VLFEAT on Octave(Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I could use vlfeat in Octave (on Windows 7) with the following procedure:

1) Download the vlfeat binaries from the [website](http://www.vlfeat.org/download.html).

2) Copy the "toolbox" subfolder somewhere, say "D:\".

3) Rename it to "D:\vlfeat_octave"

4) Run Octave, and run `addpath(genpath("D:\vlfeat_octave"))` and then `savepath`

5) Quit Octave and start again.

Then I could use vlfeat without any issues.